Strict white noise and weak white noise that is strict stationary implication
Let A is a strict white noise.
Let B is a weak white noise that is strict stationary.
What is more general, i.e. does A=>B or B=>A?
I know that strict white noise should have zero mean ad finite nonzero variance, but I can't get the implication.
Thank you.

Does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444689 answer your question?  If not, then maybe you're really asking for the definition of "strict stationary," which you can find in many of our posts that use this term.  Additional searching turned up my discussion of white noise and stationarity at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/574612/919 (I had forgetten all about it...). The examples there might be helpful.

@whuber , I know that if a process is a strict whie noise than it is weak white noise. But does it also strict stationary process? Or implication is in another direction?
